# I'm using SOAP Services ,How to get values from a dictionary in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, soap, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I'm working on SOAP, I got an response below from xml parsing.

```
{
 “NewResponse”: {
"status": "success",
"Response": {
  "status": "success",
  “MobileNumber”: "",
  “Current Value”: "44.880",
  “Type”: "P1",
  "Available": "135",
  “Old Value“: "44.880"
},
"IN_REC": “1~2”
}
}
```

How can I get the old price value and Current Value.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the json object as below. Here `jsonString` is your response in `NSString` format.

```
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", error);
else{
    NSLog(@"%@",[dic valueForKeyPath:@"NewResponse.Response.Current Value"]);
}
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks, But I'm not using JSON Parsing. I'm using XML Parsing.